# Mixing route and query parameters using FOSRestBundle with Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle

Using Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle I am attempting to implement API methods that have some number of fixed parameters defined in the route along with some optional parameters that may exist in the query string.

For example:

```
 http://somesite.com/api/method/a/b
 http://somesite.com/api/method/c/d?x=1&y=2
```

According to [the documentation for FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md), ParamFetcher is the proper way to do this, using the @QueryParam annotation. However, I already have a controller defined like:

```
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
 use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;

 class MyController extends Controller
 {

   /**
    * @Get("/method/{a}/{b}")
    * @View()
    */
   public function getMethodAction($a, $b)
   {
     // do stuff

     return array('foo' => 'bar');
   }

 }
```

Now it seems I need to be able to get access to an instance of ParamFetcher, but I don't know how (and Google searches have not helped much). I know from the documentation that I can simply change the method signature to incorporate ParamFetcher, however, when I do that it moves the parameters into the query string, which I can't have.

Is there a way to mix the two, or should I give up on ParamFetcher and go to just inspecting the request directly using Symfomy's built-in Request object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question is quite old and you probably found a solution already but since I got here through Google search and know an answer I will contribute.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Returns a collection of Task
     *
     * @QueryParam(name="projectId", nullable=true, requirements="\d+")
     * @QueryParam(name="name", nullable=true, description="Project Name")
     * @QueryParam(name="assignee", nullable=true)
     * @QueryParam(name="depth", nullable=true)
     *         *
     * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
     * @ApiDoc()
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function cgetTaskAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        foreach ($paramFetcher->all() as $criterionName => $criterionValue) {
            // some logic here, eg building query
        }

        $results = // query database using criteria from above

        // this is just a simple example how to return data
        return new JsonResponse($results);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up -- I eventually did figure this out and neglected to come back to it.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to post an answer because the original answer only uses QueryParams, and the question was using QueryParams together with RouteParams.

If you want to use route params and query params, you can use the ParamFetcher as first argument to the action and add the route arguments later.

I have not yet found a way to add the route params to the paramFetcher.

```
/*
 * @Route("/term/{termId}", requirements={"termId" = "[a-z0-9]+"})
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="limit", requirements="\d+", default="30", description="How many documents to return.")
 *
 * @Method("GET")
 *
 * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
 * @param $termId
 * @return array()
 */
public function getTermFeedAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher, $termId) {
    // access $termId over the method parameter
    // access the @queryparams via the $paramFetcher

}
```

Comment: A better answer as it does not disrupt the route param injection.