# FOSRestBundle "Some mandatory parameters are missing (id)" with route parameters

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm using Symfony 2.7.3 with FOSRestBundle to build one REST api. My model has `user` and has `tickets`. User can have tickets and I want to fetch user tickets by calling /user/{id}/tickets endpoints. My api has page and limit query parameters. I'm using `param_fetch_listener: force` to have my method parameters injected. I'm trying to mix route parametes and query parameters and I'm getting the error `"Some mandatory parameters are missing (id)"`. My method anotations are:

```php
  /**
 * @Get("/users/{id}/tickets")
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true
 * )
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="page", requirements="\d+")
 * @QueryParam(name="limit", requirements="\d+")
 */
public function getUsersTicketsAction($id, $page, $limit) {
    // my code
}
```

When I reach the endpoint I'm getting the error: `"Some mandatory parameters are missing (\"id\") to generate a URL for route \"api_1_get_users_tickets\"."`. Any ideas on how to solve it? Thanks!

---

EDIT: the code above is working fine. The error message is related to some code I had inside `// my code`. I tried my method with empty return and it worked. I was missing my id inside some internal logic. Sorry for the confusion. I'll think about closing this issue or maybe keeping it here for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: can you add the url you use to reach your web service ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22231462/3675759